# No class color syntax highlighting in TypeScript, in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, syntax-highlighting, typescript1.8

I'm using Typescript in VS2015, and the color syntax highlighting fells broken, especially on class types.

For example, when defining this module:

[image: child module]

And using it:

[image: parent module]

The class name is long but colored.

But if I use an import statement to get a more usable class name, I get this:

[image: parent module with bad highlighting]

That isn't very readable...
I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I think it should be. The fact is that the type is declared using the keyword "import" statement, so the analyzer considers variable as module rather than  as a class, and therefore no highlights it.

But if you use the keyword "type", the class name will be highlighted

Comment: How is the keyword "type" applied in the import statement?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try deleting: %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

running devenv /setup from the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 (as an admin)

and then open VS.